# Cannot uninstall an application in Samsung Galaxy A5 (2015 edition)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-a5

I have developed an application and installed the app by running the code on my device. The problem is, only this application cannot be uninstalled. I have tried both the settings>Application Manager>App>Uninstall and Uninstall by dragging from Home.

Every time I try to uninstall by dragging, it shows package installed has stopped. From Settings, when I click on the application, it shows Settings has stopped and throws me out of the Application manager.

Can anyone tell me, what is the possible cause of it and how can I get rid of that specific application? Or at least, what are the ways to do that?

I have tried adb uninstall "package name" which shows failure [Delete_failed_Internal_Error]

N.B: My phone is not rooted.So better if suggested without rooting.

Comment: Try uninstalling it, while in safe mode. Edit your question, if you tried that too

Comment: Same issues. Not working in safe mode as well.

Comment: Tried uninstalling using `adb` ?

Comment: @GokulNC quoting: *I have tried adb uninstall "package name" which shows failure [Delete_failed_Internal_Error]*

Comment: Sorry, I meant `adb shell pm uninstall <package_name>`

Comment: Is your application a device administrator by any chance? You'll need to turn off device administrator from the app settings before you can uninstall it.

Comment: @GokulNC, tried, same issues

Comment: @DanHulme, how do I check that when I can't even click on the app from the settings? "Setings has stopped" is thrown everytime I click on the app to see details from Application Manager

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that line of the question. Is there something special about this app, or system modifications on this phone? It shouldn't normally be possible for an app to screw up the system in this way.